# MySQL explain output format in JSON

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Can somebody explain the what's the `query_cost` and `cost_info` fields in the output of `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` in MySQL. I know that mysql costs are calculated with cost values defined in the table `mysql`.`server_cost` and `mysql`.`engine_cost`, But I'm not able to understand what are the steps are accounted in `query_cost`, `read_cost`, `eval_cost`, `prefix_cost`, `data_read_per_join`

An example `EXPAIN FORMAT=JSON` output is added for reference.
I did very simple query like this `

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT * FROM test WHERE id >= 1 and id <= 9;
```

And the output is...

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "2.06"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "test",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "PRIMARY"
      ],
      "key": "PRIMARY",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "id"
      ],
      "key_length": "4",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 9,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 9,
      "filtered": "100.00",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "1.16",
        "eval_cost": "0.90",
        "prefix_cost": "2.06",
        "data_read_per_join": "288"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "catIds"
      ],
      "attached_condition": "((`test_dec_2022`.`test`.`id` >= 1) and (`test_dec_2022`.`test`.`id` <= 9))"
    }
  }
}
```

Understanding of MySQL explain statement output in JSON format.

Comment: I have seen that thread they didn't explain the cost part.